# HTML input fields margin

Tags: html, css

I want to make 3/4 input fields next to each other, with a margin in between. However, using a margin makes the last inputfield too big/too short(using calc).

Been trying to figure out how to do this but can't seem to find a solution

How my current CSS code looks like:

```
input {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: calc(33% - 20px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Background has a 75% width and padding

[Current result](https://image.ibb.co/h8EYc0/chrome-2018-11-20-02-36-19.png)

[Wanted result](https://image.ibb.co/chZoAL/chrome-2018-11-20-02-36-19.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this work but it will work for one row only

```
input {
   background-color: darkgreen;
   border: none;
   color: white;
   flot:left:
   padding: 5px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   width: calc(33.333333% - 20px);
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

input + input{
   margin-left: 30px;
}
```

If you want to use for multiple rows then you can use below the structure.

```css
  

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  :after,
  :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .form-row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
  }

  .form-row:before,
  .form-row:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
  }

  .input-box {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 33.3333333%;
    float: left;
  }

  .input-field {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: white;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="input-box">
      <input type="text" class="input-field" value="input 01">
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
      <input type="text" class="input-field" value="input 02">
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
      <input type="text" class="input-field" value="input 03">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that all three of your elements have the full `margin-right` applied to them. If you want your final `<input>` element to stretch to the edge of the container, you'll want to only apply the `margin-right` to the first two `<input>` elements.

The best way to do this would be to combine the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) pseudo-classes, as can be seen in the following:

```css
input {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: calc(33% - 20px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input />
<input />
<input />
```

Note that this will have the added effect of making all three `<input>` elements slightly wider, as their `width` calculation is now derived from a larger container.